# Sending SOAP Request to WebService error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I got this exception when is send my SOAP request to my Web Service "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.". The WebService has 2 parameters (int a , int b). If i remove those two parameters, then i won't get any exception.

This i my first experience with SOAP+WS. What do i do wrong?
Thanks for taking your time.

Edit:
My college just found the error in my code. I was sending the  with an invalid header.

Here is the missing header part:

```
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Add");
```

Also, the url I'm using was incorrect.
Wrong:

```
http://localhost:62830/Service1.asmx/Add
```

Correct:

```
http://localhost:62830/Service1.asmx
```

Here are my code
Client that send SOAP to WebService

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var url = UrlTextBox.Text;
        var xml_file_path = FileTextBox.Text;

        XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
        xml_doc.Load(xml_file_path);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.Timeout = 30 * 1000;

        Stream request_stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        xml_doc.Save(request_stream);
        request_stream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream r_stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader response_stream = new StreamReader(r_stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string sOutput = response_stream.ReadToEnd();

        ResultTextBox.Text = sOutput;

    }
```

Here the XML file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" >
        <a>5</a>
        <b>10</b>
        </add>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

And here the code in WebService

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe reading them as string and then converting to int might help

Comment: My plan later is to send a complex collection of items to web service. Reading them as string would be alot of work to convert them to complex class.

Answer (score 0):

Building SOAP envelopes manually does not seem to be a good idea. You should rely on WSDL to "Add web reference", and go for WCF.

Anyway, here is part of the configuration I use for WS in web.config

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
  <conformanceWarnings>
    <remove name="BasicProfile1_1"/>
  </conformanceWarnings>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```

Also, you can check if the WS works in GET mode by connecting directly to the .asmx (in localhost mode)

Don't know if it matters, but I would have written the envelope slightly differently.
And I would have added the header "Content-Length".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <a xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">5</a>
    <b xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">10</b>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips. The code is a part of an existing client/web service application. I'm not sure if this would be easy to convert them to the solution you have suggested.